# Objective C - OpenGL ES | [EAGLView] unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I have an IOS app with two ViewController and both are working with Opengl ES.

I have a button which allows me to go from the first ViewController to the second one.
however, after touching the button, my app crash with this error message :

```
[EAGLView setDrawableDepthFormat:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e5daa00
```

Here my code :

**ViewControllerB.m**

```
@interface ViewControllerB ()
{
    ....

    PointCloudRenderer *_renderer;

    ....

}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                  target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(dismissView)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.title = @"Point Cloud viewer";
    }

    // GL setup
    _renderer = [[PointCloudRenderer alloc] initWithCols:DATA_COLS rows:DATA_ROWS];
    if (!_renderer) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create renderer.");
        return;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.context = _renderer.context;
    GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
    view.context = self.context;
    view.drawableDepthFormat = _renderer.drawableDepthFormat; //Crash here



    [self setupGestureRecognizer];
}
```

**PointCloudRenderer.m**

```
- (PointCloudRenderer *)initWithCols:(size_t)cols rows:(size_t)rows
{
   self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
   // self.context = [EAGLContext currentContext];
    assert (self.context != nil);
    if (!self.context) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
        return nil;
    }

    _cols = cols;
    _rows = rows;

    _fx = QVGA_F_X/QVGA_COLS*cols;
    _fy = QVGA_F_X/QVGA_ROWS*rows;
    _cx = QVGA_C_X/QVGA_COLS*cols;
    _cy = QVGA_C_Y/QVGA_ROWS*rows;

    _pointsData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:cols * rows * 3 * sizeof(float)];
    _imageData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:cols * rows * 4 * sizeof(char)];

    [self initGL];
    return self;
}

- (void)initGL
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    //Enable shader
    [self loadShaders];

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_pointArray);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_pointArray);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_pointBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _pointBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _cols * _rows * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat) + sizeof(gTestPoints), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(gTestPoints), gTestPoints);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_colorBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _colorBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _cols * _rows * 4 * sizeof(GLbyte) + sizeof(gTestPointColors), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(gTestPointColors), gTestPointColors);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribColor);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, GL_TRUE, 4 * sizeof(GLubyte), NULL);

    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);

}

- (GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat)drawableDepthFormat
{
    return GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;
}
```

I really do not know why my app crashed. I was careful of initializing well OpenGl ES.
Could you please help me ?

Thank

Comment: Your view is an `EAGLView` not a `GLKView`. `drawableDepthFormat` is a method on `GLKView`. Where are you creating your view? You may want to create your view controller as a subclass of `GLKViewController` so that you can work with a `GLKView`.

Comment: I create my view with the method (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil . Is it right ? 
Do you mean that my ViewControllerB will be a subclass of GLKViewController ? Thank